# Reverse url not found

Tags: python, django, web

what is this error?
AttributeError at /size/uspolo10/
'str' object has no attribute 'get'a valid view function or pattern name.
I got this error.
I can't understand this situation that 'str' and 'get'.
Please help me to solve this error.
I hope with these edits I have answered all comments, if not please comment again.
[image: this the error that I got]
views.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True,default='New')
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    schargeinc = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True,default=-1)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Sizes_class, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=False)
    selcsize = models.CharField(default=False,null=True,blank=True,max_length=25)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        
    def get_add_cart_wsize_url(self):
        return reverse("core:size", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
        
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    
    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

size.html

```
<form method="POST" action="." >
{% csrf_token %}
<div id="exampleModalPopovers" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalPopoversLabel">
        <h5>Select a size</h5>
        {% for size in object.size.sizes_choice %}
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input id="{{ forloop.counter }}"  name="sizes_choice" value="{{ size }}" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ size }}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md my-0 p">
          Set
        </a>
      </div>
</div>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
path('size/<slug>/', size, name='size'),
```

views.py

```
@login_required 
def size(request, slug): 
item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug) 
if request.method == "POST": 
    item.selcsize = item.selcsize+str(request.POST.get('sizes_choice')) 
    item.save() 
    messages.info(request, "This item is selected with size "+order_item.selcsize) 
    return redirect(item.get_absolute_url)
return reverse("core:size", kwargs={ 'slug':slug })
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: You posted your model not your view

Comment: put code in question, not comment - it will be more readable and more people it will see.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: full error should show you in which line is problem so you could use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to check what you have in variables. It seem one of variable is a string but you treat it as a dictionary and this can gives message like  `"str" has no "get()"`

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is in views.py it is not pointed to current view